# How to hide image control when it has no URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had Repeater control which had image control sometimes this image control hadnot data and I want to hide it when it hadnot data I did the code but it displayed as image without data (Not avaliable ) please any one help me.
Note : That data come from data base so Img Had Id from database but without value (NULL)

```
protected void DLHome_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    Image Img = e.Item.FindControl("ModelLogo") as Image;
    using (SqlConnection con = Connection.GetConnection())
    {
        string Sql = "Select Logo From Model";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(Sql, con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string Img2 = dr["Logo"].ToString();
            if (Img2 == System.DBNull.Value.ToString())
            {
                Img.Visible = false;
            }
        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do it would be to **retrieve the Logo data in the original query** that is used to populate your Repeater. Then you will be able to set the Visible property on your image based on that data, rather than having to perform a new datbase Query when each row is bound. This will boost performance of your page a lot.

Concerning the code that you have posted, you are not passing an image id to the SQLCommand

```
   string Sql = "Select Logo From Model where ImageId = @ImageId";

   //Assuming List<ImageModel> is what you are binding to the repeater
   ImageModel model = e.Item.DataItem as ImageModel; 
   com.Parameters.Add("@ImageId", SqlDbType.Int32, model.ImageId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the property has been assigned with an empty string somewhere? Try using `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Img.ImageUrl))
{
    Img.Visible = false;
}
```

As a side note, this could be made shorter (choose whichever style suits you best):

```
Img.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Img.ImageUrl);
```

Comment: Note : That data come from data base so Img Had Id from database but without value (NULL)